# What is the conceptual difference between SynchronizationContext and TaskScheduler

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, system.reactive, conceptual

[Stephen Toub blogged](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/) that

> Both SynchronizationContext and TaskScheduler are abstractions that
> represent a “scheduler”, something that you give some work to, and it
> determines when and where to run that work. There are many different
> forms of schedulers. For example, the ThreadPool is a scheduler: you
> call ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem to supply a delegate to run, that
> delegate gets queued, and one of the ThreadPool’s threads eventually
> picks up and runs that delegate. Your user interface also has a
> scheduler: the message pump.

So [`System.Reactive.Concurrency.EventLoopScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.concurrency.eventloopscheduler%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx), [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.aspx), [SyncrhonizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx), and [IScheduler implementations of Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242963%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) are all "schedulers" in that sense.

What is the difference between them?

Why were they all necessary? I think I get EventLoop, Dispatcher, ThreadPool. IScheduler are also well explained.
But TaskScheduler and SyncrhonizationContext still not clear to me.

[Stephen Cleary's excellent article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) explains SyncrhonizationContext, and I think I get it. Why then we needed TaskScheduler, is not clear.

Please explain or point to a source.

Comment: There might be a number of reasons, as Answers suggest. One another that is not mentioned yet I found in this MSDN Blog article: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259082.aspx
It says that SyncrhonizationContext.Post asyncronous method does not provide notification when the work item is executed. The article suggests how to add an extension method that uses TaskCompletionSource to return a Task.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each platform has it's own "scheduler" and they have their own abstractions around them.  e.g. WinForms uses a message pump.  WPF uses another message pump abstracted within "Dispatcher".  A ThreadPool is another "scheduler" abstracted within "ThreadPool".  These (and some others) are lower-level schedulers.

A Task and a TaskScheduler would like the user of a Task to not have to think about scheduling tasks at these lower levels (you can of course, in an abstracted way).  You should be able to start a task and an ambient "scheduler" should take care of it.  For example, `TaskFactory.StartNew(()=>{LengthyOperation()})` should work regardless of what platform I'm running under.  That's where a `SynchronizationContext` comes in.  It knows about what lower-level schedulers are involved in the currently running framework.  That is passed along to a `TaskScheduler` and that scheduler can both schedule tasks (possibly on to the ThreadPool) and schedule continuations through the lower-level scheduler associated with the currently running framework (see `SynchronizationContext`) to maintain synchronization requirements.  e.g. although you'd like your Task to run in the ThreadPool, you may want a continuation to run in the UI thread.

It's important to know that the `TaskScheduler` is a abstraction of multiple other schedulers.  This isn't the only reason it exists, but one of the reasons for this "extra" abstraction".

Comment: _SynchronizationContext comes in. It knows about what lower-level schedulers are involved in the currently running framework_ - if it knows that, why do we need `TaskScheduler`? For instance: _All delegates queued to the WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext are executed one at a time; they’re executed by a specific UI thread in the order they were queued._ [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) If a `SynchronizationContext` can schedule tasks for execution, then I still can't see the need for `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: _That is passed along to a TaskScheduler_ - **what** is passed to `TaskScheduler`?

Comment: `TaskScheduler` is abstract, so technically nothing is passed to it.  It's the implementations of `TaskScheduler` that would accept information passed to them.  What they need to function is dependent on each implementation though.  For the two `TaskScheduler` implementations in the Fx now, you don't create them yourself, you accept a singleton of one of them.  In general you don't care what is passed to these.  Maybe I've missed the point of your question though; if so, could you please clarify?

Comment: There's an easy explanation here that I think clarified the topic a bit - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/09/22/9898090.aspx It looks like there's nothing special about `TaskScheduler` itself, it just makes the code cleaner - instead of passing delegates to `SynchronizationContext`, which is the thing that knows the details of the current platform, we can use `TaskScheduler` to simply pass tasks to it. Not sure if it agrees with your interpretation though.

Comment: Also: _The default TaskScheduler acts like the default SynchronizationContext, queuing the tasks to the ThreadPool._ [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx)

Comment: Can you point me to an example for `although you'd like your Task to run in the ThreadPool, you may want a continuation to run in the UI thread.`?

Comment: @variable Anything you need to do with the UI (like change a control value, or change what is visible) then you need to do that on the UI thread.

Answer (score 30):

I was just reading `CLR via C#` book by Jeffrey Ritcher and thanks to him I can also give some easy explanation related to that topic. (assuming that I am not fully agreed with the whole details in answers)

First of all, `TaskScheduler` object is responsible for executing scheduled tasks. The FCL ships with two `TaskScheduler`-derived types: ***the thread pool task scheduler*** and a ***synchronization context task scheduler***. By default, all applications use the
thread pool task scheduler. This task scheduler schedules tasks to the thread pool’s worker threads. You can get a reference to the default task scheduler by querying `TaskScheduler`’s static `Default` property.

The synchronization context task scheduler is typically used for applications sporting a graphical user interface.  This task scheduler schedules all tasks onto the application’s GUI thread
so that all the task code can successfully update UI components like buttons, menu items, and so on.
The synchronization context task scheduler does not use the thread pool at all. You can get a reference to a synchronization context task scheduler by querying `TaskScheduler`’s static `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` method.

As you can see from [`SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskScheduler.cs,30e7d3d352bbb730,references) implementation, internally it uses `SynchronizationContext` field. `FCL` defines a base class, called `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext`, which solves all these problems:

- GUI applications impose a threading model where the thread that
  created a UI element is the only thread allowed to update that UI
  element. This is a problem, because your code will throw an exception
  if it tries to update UI elements via a thread pool thread. Somehow,
  the thread pool thread must have the GUI thread update the UI
  elements.
- ASP.NET applications allow any thread to do whatever it wants. When a thread pool thread starts to process a client’s request, it can
  assume the client’s culture, allowing the web server to return
  culture-specific formatting for numbers, dates, and times. In
  addition, the web server can assume the client’s identity, so that the
  server can access only the resources that the client is allowed to
  access. When a thread pool thread spawns an asynchronous operation,
  it may be completed by another thread pool thread, which will be
  processing the result of an asynchronous operation. While this work
  is being performed on behalf of the original client request, the
  culture and identity needs to “ﬂow” to the new thread pool thread so
  any additional work done on behalf of the client is performed using
  the client’s culture and identity information.

Simply stated, ***a `SynchronizationContext`-derived object connects an application model to its threading model***. The FCL defines several classes derived from
SynchronizationContext, but usually you will not deal directly with these classes; in fact, many of them are not publicly exposed or documented.

For the most part, application developers do not need to know anything about the `SynchronizationContext` class. When you `await` a `Task`, the calling thread’s `SynchronizationContext`
object is obtained. When a thread pool thread completes the `Task`, the `SynchronizationContext`
object is used, ensuring the right threading model for your application model. So, when a ***GUI thread
`awaits` a `Task`, the code following the `await` operator is guaranteed to execute on the GUI thread as
well***, allowing that code to update UI elements. For an ASP.NET application, ***the code following the
await operator is guaranteed to execute on a thread pool thread that has the client’s culture and
principal information associated with it***.

You can, of course, define your own class derived from `TaskScheduler` if you have special task
scheduling needs. Microsoft has provided a bunch of sample code for tasks and includes the source
code for a bunch of task schedulers in the Parallel Extensions Extras package. Like, `IOTaskScheduler`, `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler`, `OrderedTaskScheduler`, `PrioritizingTaskScheduler`, `ThreadPerTaskScheduler`.

Answer (score 14):

Although, as quoted,

> Both SynchronizationContext and TaskScheduler are abstractions that
>   represent a “scheduler”

IMO, degree of abstraction (and hence API) differs. SynchronizationContext is a more generic API in a sense that Post/Send takes a simple method delegate.

On the other hand, TaskScheduler is an abstraction that is specific to TPL - so it offers methods such as QueueTask which deals with `Task` object. Using synchronization context instead of task-scheduler (i.e. having a TPL specific implementation of SynchronizationContext) would have made it more tedious to work with task scheduling (and of course, it would be a weakly typed API in context of TPL). So TPL designers have chosen to model an abstract scheduler API which make sense for TPL (that's the purpose of abstraction anyway - right?) - of course, to bridge the gap, FCL contains an internal class `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler` that is wrapper TaskScheduler implementation over SynchronizationContext.

*SynchronizationContext was introduced in .NET 2.0 while TPL was introduced in .NET 4. Its interesting to think what FCL designers would have chosen if the sequence was other way round i.e. what if TPL had existed at the time of .NET 2.0. IMO, TaskScheduler could have been used instead of SynchrinizationContext by modelling delgates as task in specific specialization.*

Comment: Thanks Vinay. I also assumed that one was simly newer then the other.  What still baffles me is that every async library seems to insist on desinging its own abstraction, even though they belong to the same generation. Look at the Rx (Reactive Extensions), which is also NET 4. They got IScheduler and a number of implementations. Nothing to do with Task. And this time it is not an abstract class but an interface. Given that multiplicity of libraries, each with its own strengths, but hugely overlapping none the less, I wish there would be a book, or an article sorting it all out.

Comment: @MichaelKariv, AFAIK, Rx is not part of FCL - its a library developed & released after .NET 4. It may or may not be added to next version of Fx. Said that, I believe that you will keep seeing multiple abstractions of same concept simply because one abstraction may not *fit* very nicely with all scenarios (fitment not from functionality perspective but rather interface perspective)

Comment: SynchronizationContext is more about requirements about execution affinity.  For example, if you want to update a control, you need to do that on a UI thread.  That requirement is abstracted within a SychronizationContext.  How individual tasks are scheduled in relation to one another and where they are run (for which a Synchronization *may* be needed) is abstracted within a TaskScheduler.  Related, but orthogonal abstractions.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: so, SynchroContext is about "where", and Scheduler is about "where" and "what order". Hence, they are **not** orthogonal. If Scheduler were only about "what order", they they'd be really orthogonal. As they are, they just overlap. I personally like to view SynCtx as "lower-level" "case-specific" building block for implementing a (Task)Scheduler. But not orthogonal!