# How to make ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair work with async and await

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

I have following code:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair concurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair(TaskScheduler.Default, 4);
    var factory = new TaskFactory(concurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair.ConcurrentScheduler);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        factory.StartNew(ThreadTask);
    }

    concurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair.Complete();

    await concurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair.Completion;
    Console.WriteLine("Completed");
}

private static async Task ThreadTask()
{
    var random = new Random();
    await Task.Delay(random.Next(100, 200));
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
}
```

and program finishes executing before tasks are completed. I understand why does it happens as `ThreadTask` returns completed task and from `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` point of view it does finish executing. I also know few workarounds but is there any correct way to run this pattern with async?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of the `TaskScheduler` was devised before the advent of the async/await, and it ended up not being compatible with it. You can see an experiment that demonstrates this incompatibility here: [How to run a Task on a custom TaskScheduler using await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428604/how-to-run-a-task-on-a-custom-taskscheduler-using-await/57702536#57702536)

The abstraction that is available for controlling the behavior of async/await is the [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext). It is quite similar to a `TaskScheduler`. So much actually that some people have been wondering why we need both: [What is the conceptual difference between SynchronizationContext and TaskScheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580061/what-is-the-conceptual-difference-between-synchronizationcontext-and-taskschedul).

If you are interested for something like a `SingleThreadSynchronizationContext`, you can find an implementation here: [`Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/)

Answer (score 2):

`TaskScheduler` is compatible with `async`/`await`, but some of the behavior can be surprising.

When `await` captures its context, [it captures the current `SynchronizationContext` *unless it is `null`*, in which case it captures the current `TaskScheduler`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). So, `ThreadTask` will begin executing with the concurrent scheduler, and after its `await` it will resume on that same concurrent scheduler.

However, the semantics can be surprising, because the way `async` works with a task scheduler is that the `async` method is split into *multiple* tasks. Each `await` is a "split" point where the method is broken up. And *only those smaller tasks* are what is actually *scheduled* by the `TaskScheduler`.

So in your case, your code is starting 10 `ThreadTask` invocations, each running on the concurrent scheduler, and each of them hits an `await` point. Then the code calls `Complete` on the scheduler, which tells it not to accept any more tasks. Then when the `await`s complete, they schedule the `async` method continuation (as a task) to that task scheduler, which as already been completed.

So, while technically `await` was designed to work with `TaskScheduler`, in practice few people use it that way. In particular, the "concurrent" and "exclusive" task schedulers can have surprising semantics, since a method that is suspended due to an `await` does not count as "running" to a task scheduler.